# IInputSelectionProvider not considered by listeners of RCP SelectionService

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a RCP application with different views. The views should interact with each other through the Eclipse SelectionService.
In view 1 I have added a SelectionListener with

```java
getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(this.listener);
```

In view 2 I have added a SelectionProvider with

```java
getSite().setSelectionProvider(this);
```

To get this working, I implemented the methods from the IInputSelectionProvider in view 2. When I run my program, view 1s selection listener is not invoked. After debugging, 
I found out that view 1 is not added in the list of listeners of view 2. In view 2 I have a method

```java
private ListenerList listenersList = new ListenerList();

@Override
public void addSelectionChangedListener(ISelectionChangedListener iselectionchangedlistener) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  listenersList.add(iselectionchangedlistener);
}
```

which adds listeners to the IInputSelectionProvider. My question is: Who should call this method. My understanding is that Eclipse SelectionService should does this with

```java
getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(this.listener);
```

But it doesn't work. Do I have to fill the listenerList by myself? If yes, why do I have to use the SelectionService at all?
Or do I have to iterate through the list of listeners by calling any other method and not using the list at all? Because if I inspect the ISelectionService object

`ISelectionService service = getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService();`

I see all the listeners.
But they are not part of the listenerList above.

Comment: Are you calling `ISelectionProvider.setSelection`?

Comment: Yes, I do. I use this implementation: @Override
  public void setSelection(final ISelection iselection) {
    Object listeners[] = listenersList.getListeners();
    for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
      final ISelectionChangedListener l = (ISelectionChangedListener) listeners[i];
      SafeRunnable.run(new SafeRunnable() {

        public void run() {
          l.selectionChanged(new SelectionChangedEvent(ViewFileValues.this,iselection));
        }

      });
    }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addSelectionChangedListener is called every time a view gets activated and removed when a view is not longer active. This means: If View A is active and 'setSeletion' is called, all views which are listening are notified. If these views by themselves call 'setSelection' nothing happens. No notification is started.